# 404 Not Found JS and CSS

Tags: liferay, http-status-code-404

I have a portlet deployed on my Liferay/Tomcat server. The **portlet.xml** is calling the init param "/index.html". This file renders fine on my portal.

I have `/css` and `/js` folders on the same level as my **index.html**, under the /docroot.

I link them like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/somejs.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyles.css">
```

The file structure:

```
 /docroot/
        /css/
        /js/
        index.html
```

However, I'm getting these 404's

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/web/guest/js/somejs.js"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/web/guest/css/mystyles.css"
```

My folders won't get recognized unless I type this explicitly link my portlet like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="MyPortlet/js/somejs.js"></script>
```

This is undesirable, as the name of the portlet may change in the future and I'll have to rename all `<script>`'s and `<link>` references.

Any ideas fix this issue? Does I need a global context path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution1 (quick fix) :** Add below code in your JSP

```
<script src="<%=renderRequest.getContextPath()%>/js/somejs.js"></script> 
<link   href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

**Solution 2 (Liferay recommended) :** add below code in `liferay-portlet.xml` and let Liferay load the css & js files.

```
<header-portlet-css>/css/mystyles.css</header-portlet-css>
<footer-portlet-javascript>/js/somejs.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
```

But i would suggest keep your all js and css file into theme and access from there

Comment: nice that you included the recommended and best practice. Thanks.